# CosmosDB ChangeFeedProcessor: Can I use 2 separate ChangeFeedProcessor hosts for processing the same unpartitioned feed?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I currently have 2 separate microservices monitoring the same unpartitioned CosmosDB collection (let's call it `MasterCollection`).

I only ever want one microservice to process `MasterCollection`'s change feed at any given time - the rationale for having 2 separate hosts monitor the same feed basically boils down to redundancy.

This is what I'm doing in code (note that only the first `hostName` param differs - every other param is identical):

*microservice #1*:

```
ChangeFeedEventHost host = new ChangeFeedEventHost("east", monitoredCollInfo, leaseCollInfo, feedOptions, feedHostOptions);
```

*microservice #2*:

```
ChangeFeedEventHost host = new ChangeFeedEventHost("west", monitoredCollInfo, leaseCollInfo, feedOptions, feedHostOptions);
```

My testing seems to indicate that this works (only one of them processes the changes), but I was wondering if this is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Change Feed Processor library has a load balancing mechanism that will share the load between them as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#using-the-change-feed-processor-library).

Sharing the load means that they will distribute the Leases among themselves. Each Lease represents a Partition Key Range in the collection.

In your scenario, where you are creating 2 hosts for the same monitored collection using the same lease collection, the effect is that they will share the load and each will hold half of the leases and process changes only for those Partition Key Ranges. So half of the partitions will be processed by the host named `west`and half by the one named `east`. If the collection is Single Partition, one of them will process all the changes while the other sits doing nothing.

If what you want is for both to process all the changes independently, you have multiple options:

1. Use a different lease collection for each Host.
2. Use the `LeasePrefix` option in the [ChangeFeedHostOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.changefeedprocessor.changefeedhostoptions.leaseprefix?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azurecosmosdbcfp-1.1.1#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_ChangeFeedProcessor_ChangeFeedHostOptions_LeasePrefix) that can be set on the Host creation. That will let you share the Lease collection for both hosts but they will track independently. Just keep in mind that the RU usage in the Lease collection will raise depending on the amount of activity your main collection has.

Comment: `If the collection is Single Partition, one of them will process all the changes while the other sits doing nothing.`

So it looks like I'm using it in a supported fashion, this is good to know!

Comment: If that's the effect you want to achieve then yes. Be aware that if both hosts have different code/logic in their Observer, only one of them will be executed.

Comment: they're identical instances, just deployed in separate geo-locales for redundancy.

I'm looking into an issue where it appears that both instances stop receiving changes after working for some period of time (~1 week, no application errors or crashes in the interim).  

I was wondering if I was misusing the ChangeFeedEventHost.  Doesn't seem like it, so thanks

Comment: The Processor logs output data by default that might help you identify the issue, if you can share those logs, we can help identify the issue.

Comment: Are these logs just written to a local flat file for debug builds?

I didn't see anything in stderr/stdout.  Wondering how I would fetch these processor logs.

Comment: It depends on your application's tracing settings. The library sends traces to [listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-listeners) for the source **ChangeFeedEventHost**. You can customize the listeners (like files).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164275/discussion-between-nciao-and-matias-quaranta).

Comment: I got a repro and have a single instance of an Error from the ChangeFeedEventHost traces.  (I couldn't access our prior convo so hopefully you'll get a notification from this comment).

Was wondering if I could get your eyes on it.

Comment: Sure, please send it to maquaran{at}microsoft.com and we can take a look at it.

Comment: wanted to close the loop since we’re engaged as a Sev B at this point, but thanks!

Comment: Jumping in here, hoping you can help @MatiasQuaranta. How should I expect this to work if I have one server running `west` and another server running `east`? Everything I've tried has resulted in the same message being processed by both hosts. Is there a way to share load across servers?

Comment: @mdickin If each host is pointing to a different Lease collection, then each host will process changes separately. If they share the Lease collection, the load will be shared among all host instances distributing Partition Key ranges among them.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, thank you for the follow up. It turned out to be a Friday afternoon mistake...I was passing in the same `Host` value for each server. Whoops!